# Does composite cluster index affect performance of seek/scan non-cluster index which is part of the composite?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, index

I have bank transaction table with columns

```
Division
Brcode
TrDate
ProjectCode
Accountnumber
EffectiveDate
DrCr
Amount
EndBalance
```

In the other table the `Brcode` itself is unique and is assigned under only 1 division.

I am planing to set `Division,Brcode,TrDate` as cluster index(composite) and set each of them as non-cluster index individually.

What I curious is

1. since `Brcode` is unique for all division so clustering `Division,Brcode,TrDate` is implicitly clustering Brcode,does `Brcode` index get benefit from this? Does it need to search all division?
2. If I search by `TrDate` it won't get benefit from cluster index,is that right? this column shouldn't include in composite?
3. If I search by `TrDate` will cause full table scan or index scan?

ps.this table have 7 millions record so even minor factor will cause a huge different :(

Comment: What datatypes are your columns?? Your **clustering key** should be **as small as possible** - best is an `INT IDENTITY`. You should avoid wide clustering keys at all costs; also try to avoid variable-length columns in a clustering key, and avoid any columns that might change their values - all those factors are horribly bad in a clustering key.

Answer (score 4):

First off, don't mix "primary key" and "clustered index". One is "how to identify a row", the other is "on-disk structure"

Then, you don't need an index on `Division` by itself because it is the left hand column of the clustered index. However, it won't be covering (see links below)

And for each point in turn:

1. this table doesn't know that "Brcode is unique for all division". If it is, then `brCode` should be first and unique and the clustered index *by itself*
2. a search on `TrDate` won't benefit from the clustered index
3. it depends on selectivity, statistics, how many columns are required. It may seek with a key lookup or it may scan the clustered index (= a table scan) or scan/seek the index on `TrDate`

Finally, I'd suggest some background reading:

- [SQL Server Index Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/)
- [Using Covering Indexes to Improve Query Performance](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)

Comment: this table doesn't have any key because bank transaction can only identify by time (which is not include in table) but it need proper index since it always have been used and has millions of record.
It is usually searched by accountnumber,occasionally by brcode or division
so brcode and accountnumber is the way to go?
I'm new to SA and DBA,I'm reading ur link.thx a lot